# Get coordinate when moving camera android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on android application google map, I need to capture latitude and longitude when I am moving a map. Currently when I am clicking it is working, but I need coordinates when I am moving a map. My code is given below:

```
private void setUpMap() {
        gMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);// add the listener for click for amap object



        gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                latitude = latlng.latitude;
                longitude = latlng.longitude;

                address=GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter.getAddress(PickLocation.this,longitude,latitude);
                edtAddressSearch.setFocusable(false);
                edtAddressSearch.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                edtAddressSearch.setText(address);

            }
        });


        gMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"map is moving",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Obtain the `LatLng` object from the [`CameraPosition`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition) variable inside `onCameraMove`:

```
@Override
public void onCameraMove() {
    LatLng target = gMap.getCameraPosition().target;
}
```